# How to capture the screen with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking

I need to make a program that checks if something appear on screen. First step was to make a screen capture. I was searching a lot and only found capturing video with webcam.

Comment: For what operating system?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Qt as it offers APIs to second part of your problem: See [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html).

If you want to detect if user has launched a new application then you will have to write a Windows (assuming MS Windows OS) service to track it and then launch screen capture application.